# how to change sticky menu when width is smaller than 644

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Hello I have this sticky menu and I want to change it to default menu when window size is smaller than 644. how can I check all the time if the browser window is resized?

```
var menu = $('#header');

    pos = menu.offset();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.height() && menu.hasClass('default')){
            menu.fadeOut(100, function(){
                $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed').fadeIn(100);
                $('#site-description').css({'display': 'none'});
                $('#logo').css({'margin-top': '5px'});
            });
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
            menu.removeClass('fixed').addClass('default');
            $('#site-description').css({'display': 'block'});
            $('#logo').removeAttr('style');                 
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

});
```

Comment: I i use it in this way http://jsfiddle.net/2Wgmk/ so when I have less than 644 width it doesn't appear but when I resize sticky menu should works but it doesn't.